# What is the correct SQL (MYSQL) for finding the value that occurs the most?

Tags: mysql, sql

What is the correct SQL (MYSQL) for finding the value that occurs the most?

Here's what I thought it might have been:

```
SELECT TOP 1 `my_field` FROM `my_table`
GROUP BY COUNT(`my_field`)
ORDER BY DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the most commonly occuring value:

```
SELECT `column`
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `column`
ORDER BY count(`column`) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: `count` is nothing special, aliased from `count('column')` in `count('column') AS 'count'`. Worked fine for me in MySQL.

Comment: Yes, just realized that.  Thanks.  Substituting `ORDER BY 'count' DESC` with `ORDER BY count('column') DESC` also works, right?